# Combining multiple sentences into one text string in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, summarize

I am trying to join separate sentences into one text object so that I can run it through the Gensim generator. In order for it to work, there need to be at least 2 sentences. According to my output, it looks as though I have more than two sentences but it says that my input is less than 2 sentences.

I have tried so many string methods and it seems as though the Gensim Summarizer doesn't pick up it is entire joined text but rather it looks at each sentence by itself.

MY CODE:

```
if w in ws:
 bc= ''.join([w for w in background_corpora])
#print(bc)
if len(bc.split('. '))<= 4:
bc_text= '.'.join(bc.split('\n'))
print(bc_text)
print("Background Content: {} ".format(summarize(bc_text))
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
`raise ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")
ValueError: input must have more than one sentence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line

```
bc_text= '.'.join(bc.split('\n'))
```

The summarize function expects a list of sentences.

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Should I append the sentences to a list because the texts I am iterating through are strings.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested and I am still receiving that error message. I have been stuck on this all day.

Comment: is that all I have to do? It still seems to not read the sentences together. It treats each line of a sentences as its own rather than the total number of sentences.

Comment: From the documentation. 

"The input should be a string, and must be longer than INPUT_MIN_LENGTH sentences for the summary to make sense. The text will be split into sentences using the split_sentences method in the gensim.summarization.texcleaner module. Note that newlines divide sentences."

For summarize to work, you need to provide it a string, which has multiple sentences, where each line is divided by a newline.